# Excel: Center across selection with cells containing nothing (as in "") but formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a to do list in Excel. The user can fill up to 10 lines per KPI for multiple KPIs. The width is fixed to 8 columns.
Afterwards, I extract that same list without empty lines into another sheet (w/o VBA). And then I export it to ppt as an OLE Object via VBA. Now the Problem is: The KPI title cannot be read because it is cut off when the cell ends even though the next cell is visibly empty (Only a Formula is in there which enters "" for empty cells) and center across selection is activated.

I somehow need to make that KPI name visible (preferably without VBA).

Note: Adding it in front of each line is not feasible due to width limitations imposed through the slides' size. Also Copy and then paste special of the OLE Data did not work.
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trynw.png)

[Selection without empty rows. Problem is Cell A3 for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ZDk.png)

Comment: If there's any content in the cell to the right then the text will be cut off: I don't think there's any way to make it flow over that cell.  What's the purpose of the "no empty lines" sheet - is it just an intermediate step before PPT?

Comment: So to be clear, there's a formula in `B3` that's returning `""`?

Comment: Have you looked at merging the cells for the KPI name, to ensure that there is enough space?  My assumption is that the key points indicator title is above the 10 lines, so you have at least 8 columns to merge for housing the KPI name.

Comment: @BruceWayne: The Cell next to it has the following code:
<pre><Code> `=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Input!E$6:E$171;MATCH(ROW()-ROW($A$2);Input!$C$6:$C$171;0));"")=0;"";IFERROR(INDEX(Input!E$6:E$171;MATCH(ROW()-ROW($A$2);Input!$C$6:$C$171;0));""))`
</br>
But you can basically omit everything but <pre><Code> `=IFERROR(INDEX(Input!E$6:E$171;MATCH(ROW()-ROW($A$2);Input!$C$6:$C$171;0));"")`. The rest is just a desperate try to get that cell empty

Comment: Sorry for my terrible try at getting those codes to work haha

Comment: @Cyril: That is definitely the case that I do not have enough space. But since in the output sheet, the line of a header must be variable, merging them does not work for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams: That sheet is basically an intermediary, that is right. Plus they can see their output pre-exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA, not sure how you could quickly do that. Perhaps a find/replace on your formula, but that would even find formulas that *don't* equate to `""`.

If you just want to clear such cells, this sub may work. Change the range to your required range:

```
Sub remove_Empty_Formula()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("B1:B10")

For Each cel In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(cel) And cel.Value = "" And cel.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
        cel.ClearContents
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks for the basis. Adjusted it to my needs.